# How to upload a file to iphone app from a computer?

Tags: iphone, file-upload

In some of the apps, I have seen its possible to upload files to the library of a certain application. They ask to type "http://192.xxx.xxx.xxx" and then to upload files to that location which inturn becomes available for download in iphone when we use the same URL.

Do anyone have an idea how to do it OR where to look for to gain info about this?

Answer (score 0):

create a HTTP server app on iPhone, so the upload file also can be implemented in the app

Comment: great answer.... but it would be great if you have mentioned how to create HTTP server